# Opencart shipment module - when choosing - user logout

Tags: php, opencart, opencart-3, opencart-module

I preparing custom shipment module. I found bug/problem? - its looks like this:

1. Login to account on the shop
2. Checkout
3. Contiunue on addresses
4. When I'm on shippment - and this custom module is active, when I click next or reload page - user is logout.

I'm using newest version 3.0.2.0 (also checking latest alfa 3.1)

Please help me :-(

I have no idea why it doesn't work.
I also notice, that user is logout also when I try to store something to session this->session->......

Edit I check this on fresh install of alfa also - doesn't work.
For best see whats happened take a look on video and package with that extension (for unknown reason - to install You need to copy those files manually)

Extension and video clip on my google drive:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=17XPqGOdTImiQpx4Ax2RlyW_opP-6SFd_

Comment: Download extension and watch video clip:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=17XPqGOdTImiQpx4Ax2RlyW_opP-6SFd_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hthis is the issue that the session saving to the DB.  DB are limited by space. Your extension have very huge list of the Paczkomat. So this data can not be saved to the DB and operation interrupting. Solution: change place where to save sessions..
In the file system/config/catalog.php
find:

```
$_['session_engine']       = 'db';
```

change to

```
$_['session_engine']       = 'file';
```

The same in the file system/config/default.php

```
$_['session_engine']       = 'db';
```

change to

```
$_['session_engine']       = 'file';
```

it less secure but helps to work with this module. I think author of the module should know that in OC version 3.0.x will be this issue with his shipping module. If you wish more better solution you can contact me kestas[at]smartechas.eu

Cheers